# Laravel password validation rule with error

Tags: laravel

Validation rule:

The password contains characters from at least three of the following five categories:

English uppercase characters (A – Z)
English lowercase characters (a – z)
Base 10 digits (0 – 9)
Non-alphanumeric (For example: !, $, #, or %)
Unicode characters

I want to use the validation rule of password like above and my code is like this. But still I can register to my system just by digits only.

```
 'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:8', 'regex:/[a-z]/', 'regex:/[A-Z]/', 'regex:/[0-9]/', 'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/','confirmed'],
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have multiple regex rules, one regex can generalize all of yours.

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$
```

Which mean, Match:

- `{8,}` Minimum eight characters (so there is no need for `min:8`)
- `A-Za-z` at least one letter of any upper and lower
- `@$!%*#?&]` at least one special char.
- `\d` number/s

so your rules now should look something like this :

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'regex:^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$','confirmed'],
```

Comment: doesn't match uni-codes and doesn't respect the 3 out of 5 condition